# RecyclerView in DialogFragment scroll up after notify change on last element

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I replaced ListViews by RecyclerViews in my project. I have dialog with recyclerview, where I want to change item in it after click. But I have problem, RecyclerView scrolls up when I try to click on last element.

In empty Activity I only create dialog like this:

```
CustDialog dlg = new CustDialog();
dlg.show(getFragmentManager(), "dlg1");
```

Dialog code here:

```
public class CustDialog extends DialogFragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}

static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    }
}

static class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    List<String> mItems;

    public MyAdapter() {
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            mItems.add("Test " + i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.minimal, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String item = mItems.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(item);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }
}
}
```

Dialog layout contains only LinearLayout with recyclerview with match_parent parameters inside. Item Layout contains LinearLayout with textview.

If you try this sample after click on last element recyclerview scrolls up  at a distance of two or three elements.

Comment: u should never create the onClickListeners inside onBindViewHolder(), because the position index doesnt return the expected value a lot of the times, thats because how the recycling works, u should implement your onClick inside the viewHolder constructor and dont forget to check {getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION} :)